# Is there any pattern for the derivative of $y'$ with respect to $y$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you calculate $\frac{d\frac{d y}{d x}}{d y}$? In addition, how would you calculate $\int y' \, dy$?

Comment: $\frac{\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}{\partial y}$ is a meaningless expression. Additionally, you can use $\int y' dy = \int\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}dy$ to compute the integral as a function of $y$ or $\int y' dy = \int (y')^2 dx$ to compute the integral as a function of $x$

Comment: Try $\int y’ dy=\int dy=y+C$

Comment: @TymaGaidash, OP means $y'=dy/dx, $ not $y'=dy/dy$

Comment: It should be obvious that the one line body of your Question has no context for Readers to guess at what you might have meant with either part by "calculate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the integral, we can calculate the derivative of $y'$ with respect to $y$

Let's define $f(x)=y$ and $g(y)=y'(x(y))$ being $x(y)=f^{-1}(y)$. Then, by the chain rule,

$\dfrac{dg}{dy}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{df}{dx}\right)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=$

$=\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}\dfrac{df^{-1}}{dy}=y''\dfrac{df^{-1}}{dy}$

and finally, by setting $h(y)=\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}(x(y))$, $\dfrac{dg}{dy}=h(y)\dfrac{df^{-1}}{dy}$

But you can calculate that derivative directly on $g(y)$

E.g.:

$y=f(x)=\ln(x)$, $x=f^{-1}(y)=e^y$

$g(y)=y'(x)=1/x=1/e^y$, $\dfrac{dg}{dy}=-1/e^y$

Or

With $y''(x)=-1/x^2=-1/e^{2y}$ and $\dfrac{df^{-1}}{dy}=e^y$

$\dfrac{dg}{dy}=-\dfrac{1}{e^{2y}}e^y=-1/e^y$

By now, I don't know how this derivative can be interpreted.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, the notation of partial differentials is ambiguous enough to not know what you are asking for.  however, I can calculate the total differential for you, however it uses a different-than-usual notation (see my paper, "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials").  In this notation, the "normal" second derivative is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$.  The notation for what you are wanting would be:

$$ \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dy} = \frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx} - \frac{dy\,d^2x}{dx^2}}{dy} = \frac{d^2y}{dx\,dy} - \frac{d^2x}{dx^2} $$

For the second problem, there's not enough information to actually calculate a solution.  The integral is really $\int \frac{dy}{dx}\,dy$.  You haven't separated variables, and this isn't a linear combination of functions, so it isn't the result of differentiating a single function of two variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also changed the expression of my question a little bit.